# 'e' in javascript numbers

Tags: javascript, numbers

I need to understand the following:

when I type `4e4` in Google Chrome's console it returns `40000`.

Can anyone help me to understand what is `e` in javascript numbers and what is the algorithm working for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [wiki: Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)

Comment: also: `4*10**4 == 4e4;`

Comment: Thanks dandavis... the easiest way to understand. I got it.

Answer (score 17):

`4e4` is a floating-point number representation.
It consists of:

1. Sign - **S**(+ or -)
2. Mantissa - **M**(some number, normalized: **1.x** where x is some sequence of digits)
3. Exponent - **E**(represents a power of 10 that is Mantissa(M) multiplied with)

It is also a way of how floating-point numbers are stored on the system. For instance, for **single-precision** we get:
[single-precision floating-point number representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rO6td.jpg)

Together, it gives us:

> `-1^S * M * p^E` where *p* is **the basis of the numerical system**

So, in common sense, p can be anything so that `4e4` could be also `4 * 5^4` **if** `p == 5`

> As we usually work with `decimal values` `p is equal to 10`

And as was answered before, `4e4 == 4 * 10^4` (as 4 is a decimal value in this case)

Comment: This answer is confusing the internal representation of floating-point numbers, in binary, with the scientific notation-inspired representation, in decimal. In particular, the comment *"normalized: 1.x"* for the mantissa doesn't make any sense outside of base 2.

Comment: The OP problem is related to floating point numbers, it is not the reason. It is about floating point representation in scientific notation, as others have quit right pointed out. double, single or whatever precision has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 14):

'e' in a number like that is the same as 'times 10 to the power of'

3.2e6 is 3.2x10^6

Answer (score 8):

`4*10^4`

If the number was `4e5` this would be equal to `4*10^5`

etc.

Comment: the simplest answer of them all

Answer (score 1):

As this question is specifically about JavaScript I think it's good to have the examples from MDN here:

```
0e-5   // 0
0e+5   // 0
5e1    // 50
175e-2 // 1.75
1e3    // 1000
1e-3   // 0.001
1E3    // 1000
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Numbers_and_dates#exponentiation