# Eliminating dashes from node crypto generated random values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, cryptography, node-crypto

There's this function in the NPM `cuid` library:

```
import * as crypto from "crypto"

var lim = Math.pow(2, 32) - 1;

export function getRandomValue () {
  return Math.abs(crypto.randomBytes(4)
    .readInt32BE(0) / lim)
}
```

The return value from this should not return values with dashes in it.

[However per my test sampling a million values, one value returned contains a dash](https://github.com/ericelliott/cuid/issues/200).

How do we eliminate the dashes?

Someone in an earlier question suggested using `%` instead of `/` and this works.  I ran 10 million samples and none of them contain dashes, so does this seem like the correct thing to do to the rest of you?

Comment: `crypto.randomBytes` is method a Node.js library, not the browser library. Are you trying to access the method in the browser or Node?

Comment: I changed the nature of the question.  I now refers to an implementation detail.

Comment: Where is the code using `cuid`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "dash" is not a hyphen.

It's the scientific notation for a number such as `8.55652615627193e-7`.

See ['e' in javascript numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39423555/266535) for a similar question.

You could use `num.toString(16)` to convert to hexadecimal which looks like `0.00000e5b00000e5b`.