# Can I use variables in JS `e` numbers?

Tags: javascript, numbers

Per ['e' in javascript numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39423555/e-in-javascript-numbers) I would like to use ['e' notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation):

Right now I'm doing:

```
const USD_DECIMALS = 2
const USD = 1e2
```

As you can see I'm duplicating the number `2`. When I'd like to do is something like:

```
const USD_DECIMALS = 2
const USD = 1e[USD_DECIMALS]
```

Is this possible? Maybe using the `Number()` constructor or similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a string out of "1e2" and then run it through Number.

```js
const USD_DECIMALS = 2
const USDString = `1e${USD_DECIMALS}`;
const USD = Number(USDString);

console.log(USD);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly (without building a dynamic string, but then that's not direct either), but since `1e2` means 1 times 10², you can use either `1 * Math.pow(10, USD_DECIMALS)` OR `1 * 10**USD_DECIMALS` to do the same thing dynamically:

```
const USD_DECIMALS = 2;
const USD = 1 * 10**USD_DECIMALS;
// Or: const USD = 1 * Math.pow(10, USD_DECIMALS);
```

Live Example:

```js
console.log("Various ways to get 10²:");
console.log(1e2);
const USD_DECIMALS = 2;
console.log(1 * Math.pow(10, USD_DECIMALS));
console.log(1 * 10**USD_DECIMALS);

console.log("Just for completeness, 10³:");
console.log(1e3);
const USD_DECIMALS3 = 3;
console.log(1 * Math.pow(10, USD_DECIMALS3));
console.log(1 * 10**USD_DECIMALS3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

*(Side note: you sometimes need `()` around [`**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Exponentiation) expressions where you may not expect to, such as in `-1 ** 10`, but not in the above.)*

---

Just being a bit silly: you *could* add an `e` method to numbers. It's never a good idea to augment native prototypes in library code, but it *can* be okay in app-specific or page-specific code that doesn't have to integrate with unknown other code like libraries do, provided you do it correctly (make the extension non-enumerable). So FWIW:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, "e", {
    value(exp) {
        return this * 10**exp;
    },
    // The usual set of flags for methods on built-in prototypes
    // (`enumerable: false` is the default, but including it here
    // just for emphasis)
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false,
});

const USD_DECIMALS = 2;
console.log(1..e(USD_DECIMALS));
console.log((1).e(USD_DECIMALS));
let value = 1; // or whatever
console.log(value.e(USD_DECIMALS));
```

I probably wouldn't do it for this. Partially because I lean toward leaving native prototypes alone even in app-/page-specific code, and also because of the awkwardness of calling methods on numeric literals. Notice how I had to use `1..e(USD_DECIMALS)` or `(1).e(USD_DECIMALS)` instead of just `1.e(USD_DECIMALS)`. That's because the `.` after a series of digits is part of the numeric literal, so it doesn't start a property/method access. The extra `.` solves that, or wrapping the literal in `()`. There's no problem when using a variable for the base value, since that's not a numeric *literal*, so `value.e(USD_DECIMALS)` works. So on the whole, for me, not worth it, but a bit of fun to look at.

Comment: I’m obviously aware re first sentence. But yes pow() is a good workaround.

Comment: @mikemaccana - For the lurkers for whom this stuff is a bit magical. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `N`e`M` is for the order of magnitude (N*10^M). What you can do is just

```js
n=n*(10**m)
```

If you actually want to control the number of decimals you have to round.